# (Python) Search for a string in a data file with possible spelling errors

Tags: python

Suppose I have a document and I'd like to search for the string "Google", but also possible typos such as "Goggle", "Gooole", "Goofle".

What I'm trying to do is figure out if there is a way to create a string with variation in each position, for example I'd want to search for
G+(o)+(o or g)+(o or g or f)+(l)+e.

Is concatenating the letters together a way to do this in Python or is there a simpler method? And can you add variation in each position without having to enter in every possible combination of letter?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I would use string distance and choose a threshold :

```
import difflib

def similarity(word, pattern):
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=word.lower(), b=pattern.lower()).ratio()

text = "Somme text with google or gooole or goofle";
lookup = "google";
threshold = 0.9

for word in text.split():
    if similarity(word, lookup) > threshold:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Note that for this example, a threshold of 0.9 gives no hits (but 0.8 works)

Comment: I would add from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/sequencematcher-examples.html) :
_As a rule of thumb, a ratio() value over 0.6 means the sequences are close matches_

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'^(Go[og][ogf]le)$', string)
```

Pythex: [Link](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(Go%5Bog%5D%5Bogf%5Dle)%24&test_string=Google%0AGoofle%0AGooole&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

There's probably a better way regular expressions aren't my specialty by any means.